# Converting lower case letters to upper case letters error : Getting just ( in the result

Tags: c

I am learning C . I have written a program which asks the user to enter their name and print-outs their name in Upper case , for example :- if a user enters Stack Overflow as his name , it print-outs STACK OVERFLOW . But when-ever I run the program it gives just ( as the output , Can you please figure it out whats wrong with the code ? I am using [Code::Blocks](http://codeblocks.org) (version 13.12) .

Here is my code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char name[25] ;
    char name_up[25] ;
    int i ;

    fputs("Enter your name : " , stdout) ;
    fgets(name , 24 , stdin) ;

    for(i=0 ; i<strlen(name) ; i++)
    {
        if(name[i] == '\n')
        {
            break ;
        }
        else
        {
            if(islower(name[i]))
            {
                name[i] = toupper(name_up[i]) ;
            }
            else
            {
                name[i] = name_up[i] ;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Entered name is : %s .\nEntered name in upper case is : %s ." , name , name_up) ;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `name[i] = name_up[i]` Shouldn't this (and the other one) be the other way around?

Comment: Means ? Can you explain it ?

Comment: You're assigning to `name`, shouldn't you be assigning to `name_up`, e.g. `name_up[i] = toupper(name[i])`.

Comment: Also, you should make sure your strings are null-terminated.

Comment: also you dont need the check if name[i] is lower, its just redundant, since everything in name_up is going to be upper case anyway

Answer (score 3):

Well, you are missing `string.h and ctype.h` header files and you had your variables reversed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char name[25] = {0};      /* initializing string arrays to null (zero) insures they */
    char name_up[25] = {0};   /* are null-terminated for strings less than 25 chars     */
    int i ;

    fputs("Enter your name : " , stdout) ;
    fgets(name , 24 , stdin) ;

    for(i=0 ; i<strlen(name) ; i++)
    {
        if(name[i] == '\n')
        {
            name[i] = 0;      /* strip newline from end of name    */
            name_up[i] = 0;   /* do not include newline in name_up */
            break ;
        }
        else
        {
            if(islower(name[i]))
            {
                name_up[i] = toupper(name[i]) ;    /* You assign name_up = name    */
            }                                      /* you had it reversed...       */
            else
            {
                name_up[i] = name[i] ;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Entered name is : %s.\nEntered name in upper case is : %s.\n" , name , name_up) ;
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$./bin/chgcase
Enter your name : StackOverflow
Entered name is : StackOverflow.
Entered name in upper case is : STACKOVERFLOW.
```

**Note:** Always initialize your variables (including arrays). That will save you lots of grief in the long run. Also, always compile with **Warnings** enabled. That will show you where the areas of concern are in your code. E.g.:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/chgcase changecase.c
```

Comment: why overweight call on each iteration? `i<strlen(name)` it is not beautiful and perhaps ugly

Comment: It is ugly. That wasn't the crux of the question. I generally try to keep as much of the OP's code as possible to prevent confusion. In the course of this code the `strlen` call repetition is negligible. Your point is well-taken. It should be calculated once, assigned to a `size_t` variable and then used in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

change `for(i=0 ; i<strlen(name) ; i++)` to `for(i=0 ; name[i] != '\n' ; i++)` and delete block:

```
    if(name[i] == '\n')
    {
        break ;
    }
```

change it:

```
        if(islower(name[i]))
        {
            name[i] = toupper(name_up[i]) ;
        }
        else
        {
            name[i] = name_up[i] ;
        }
```

to:

```
        if(islower(name[i]))
        {   
            name_up[i] = toupper(name[i]) ;
        }
        else
        {   
            name_up[i] = name[i] ;
        }
```

Oh yes, add the line `#include <ctype.h>`

yeah, forgot to add a terminating null to the end of name_up
after "for loop" add this: `name_up[i] = '\0';` and may be: `name[i] = '\0';`

Comment: So how will `name_up` be nil terminated?

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the positions of name[i] and name_up[i]. Otherwise you would override the name array with the empty name_up array.

```
else
    {
        if(islower(name[i]))
        {
            name_up[i] = toupper(name[i]) ;
        }
        else
        {
            name_up[i] = name[i] ;
        }
    }
```